# Use new temp firefox profile each time with selenium server

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

Im using the selenium server 2.35.0 which im starting using

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0`

And then running my tests from a php script using the `Testing_Selenium` binding.

It seems to be opening in the same Firefox profile each time, how can i change this ? I understand this is not the default, but it has been changed somewhere down the line and im not sure how to undo it.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the default **is** using an anonymous temporary profile.  You sure it's opening the same profile? How can you tell?

Comment: @sircapsalot - it seems to have the cookies loaded, i think it was changed some time ago on this machine, but im not sure why / how